# How do I create a conditional statement for a single computed item?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am using Bootstrap Table to display a list of items from a database table, but I would like to hide some of the items depending on the user role. Is there some way I can create an if statement for that inside the computed properties or do I need a seperate method for it?

```
    <b-form-group>
      <b-table
        :items="databaseItems"
        :fields="fields"
        :per-page="[5, 10, 20]"
        :filter-function="filter"
        :filter-debounce="200"
        :tbody-tr-attr="{style: 'cursor: pointer'}"
        sort-by="name"
        primary-key="id"
        include-filter
      >
      </b-table>
    </b-form-group>

computed: {
  fields() {
    return [
      {
        key: 'selected',
        label: ''
      },
      {
        key: 'name',
        label: this.$t('name'),
        sortable: true
      },
      {
        key: 'email',
        label: this.$t('email'),
        sortable: true
      },
      {
        key: 'phone',
        label: this.$t('phone'),
        sortable: true
      },
    ];
  },
},
```

I tried the following, but it says the element "phone" is not exported

```
  filterDataFields() {
    if (this.user.systemAdmin) {
      this.$set(this.fields, phone, true);
    } else {
      this.fields[phone] = false;
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a [filter on that array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)? Like so:

```js
    <b-form-group>
      <b-table
        :items="databaseItems"
        :fields="fields"
        :per-page="[5, 10, 20]"
        :filter-function="filter"
        :filter-debounce="200"
        :tbody-tr-attr="{style: 'cursor: pointer'}"
        sort-by="name"
        primary-key="id"
        include-filter
      >
      </b-table>
    </b-form-group>

computed: {
  fields() {
    const set = [
      {
        key: 'selected',
        label: ''
      },
      {
        key: 'name',
        label: this.$t('name'),
        sortable: true
      },
      {
        key: 'email',
        label: this.$t('email'),
        sortable: true
      },
      {
        key: 'phone',
        label: this.$t('phone'),
        sortable: true
      },
    ];
    return set.filter(item => {
      let hidden = false 

      // Add rules to an item of your set
      if (item.key == 'phone' && !this.user.systemAdmin)
        hidden = true
      
      return hidden
    })
  },
},
```

Small side note you may have already considered but just to make sure: If you run this code client-side (and thus have received the data via an api call) a user could be able to get hands on the data you have hidden using the network page of the browser’s dev tools.